# Multiple Curves on multiple Y-Axes

Tags: charts, line

I have three curves, which I visualize on the left y-Axis. But I have for comparison three other curves with very different values ​​which must visulisieren on the right y-Axis. how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question is about a certain library or charting in general.

The most easy-to-read thing to do would be to make two charts.

But if the two data sets absolutely had to be on the same chart area, one way you could address this issue is by coloring axes to coordinate with your plot lines. To get an idea of what I'm describing, please view this demo (click run on the code snippet):

```js
var chartJSON = { 
"type":"line",
        "plotarea":{
            
        },
        "scaleX":{
            "offset-start":20,
            "offset-end":20,
            "line-color":"black",
            "line-width":4,
            "tick":{
                "line-color":"black"
            }
        },
        "scaleY":{
            "line-color":"rgb(54,208,38)",
            "line-width":4,
            "tick":{
                "line-color":"rgb(54,208,38)"
            }
        },
        "scaleY2":{
            "line-color":"rgb(14,73,207)",
            "line-width":4,
            "tick":{
                "line-color":"rgb(14,73,207)"
            }
        },
        "plot":{
            "aspect":"spline"
        },
        "series":[
            {
                "values":[69,68,54,48,70,74,98,70,72,68,49,69],
                "text":"Apple",
                "line-color":"rgb(54,208,38)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(54,208,38)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[51,53,47,60,48,52,75,52,55,47,60,48],
                "text":"Microsoft",
                "line-color":"rgb(101,189,82)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(101,189,82)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[42,43,30,40,31,48,55,46,48,32,38,38],
                "text":"Oracle",
                "line-color":"rgb(164,188,157)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(164,188,157)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[1550,1520,560,1000,1830,1620,950,900,1790,800,1830,1620],
                "text":"Dell",
                "line-color":"rgb(14,73,207)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-2",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(14,73,207)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[1760,780,1110,1670,860,1400,1980,1230,1740,660,1670,860],
                "text":"Apple",
                "line-color":"rgb(47,97,207)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-2",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(47,97,207)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            },
            {
                "values":[1660,1700,1060,1590,800,960,580,1020,690,1580,1590,800],
                "text":"Microsoft",
                "line-color":"rgb(122,148,203)",
                "scales":"scale-x,scale-y-2",
                "marker":{
                    "background-color":"rgb(122,148,203)",
                    "border-color":"black"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
zingchart.render({
  id: "myChart",
  height: 300,
  width: 500,
  data: chartJSON
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.zingchart.com/playground/lib/zingchart/zingchart-html5-min.js"></script>

<div id="myChart"></div>
```

I'm on the team at ZingChart so if you have any questions about how the chart was made, please feel free to reach out.